# Parallel charging of li-ion series pack

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-design, charger

I have made a 3s lithium polymer battery pack that I am trying to make a charging unit for

My current charger setup is 3x AC/DC converters powering x3 TP5100 charger boards, each charger leading to one of the cells in the pack via the balacing connector.

I am using 3 chargers because these are plentiful for me and I would like to charge the pack as fast as possible while keeping the cells relatively top balanced. The idea behind the 3 converters was so all cells could be charged concurrently without shorting since each cell will have its own dedicated charger GND.

When I plug into AC, the 3 chargers power up fine but when I then connect the battery pack, only two of the chargers will change state. I have confirmed the wiring and the hardware are correct (per my plans)

Is there an inherent issue with this idea that I'm not aware of?
I would love to learn what is causing this and open to suggestions for improvement

TP5100 datasheet: https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1299994/TopPower/TP5100/1

[image: schematic]
[image: battery connected]

Comment: The photographs you included are more or less worthless. Please include a proper schematic and a link to the datasheet for the "chargers".

Comment: Thanks Elliot, I have updated above

Comment: Gluing 3 power supplies together like that is 'innovative' but the mains filter capacitor of one of them is right next to the TP5100. Looks dangerous! Can you show a photo of the wiring between the chargers (with power off so the lights don't obscure it)?